# comint-mode problem with C++ style comments (and quotes)?

Tags: javascript, comint

This is a rephrase of my SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147993, which didn't receive much attention in SO.

Basically, I *suspect* that I enountered a problem with [nodejs-repl.el](https://github.com/abicky/nodejs-repl.el) (which is based on `comint-mode`) when C++ style comments are mixed with quotations.

For example, when evaluated using `nodejs-repl-send-region`, the following line:

```
var says = function ( ) {  return this.saying || ''; };
```

gives an error :

```
var says = function ( ) {  return this.saying   ''; };
SyntaxError: repl: Unexpected token, expected ; (1:48)
> 1 | var says = function ( ) {  return this.saying   ''; };
```

`||` seems to have been dropped. There is no error if I replace `||` with `+`.

Another example:

```
var url = "http://www.ora.com:80/goodparts?q#fragment";
```

gives:

```
> var url = "http:/*www.ora.com:80/goodparts?q#fragment"; */
SyntaxError: repl: Unexpected token (1:56)
> 1 | var url = "http:/*www.ora.com:80/goodparts?q#fragment"; */
```

Here, `http://` seems to be misinterpreted as `http:/*`, beginning a comment, despite the fact that `//` is in a quote.

In both cases, the error *only* occurs when the problem lines are sent from the buffer to the REPL using `nodejs-repl-send-region`. No error is returned if the line is evaluated directly in the REPL.

Can anyone please help explain how to fix my Emacs environment (maybe `nodejs-repl.el` or the underlying comint-mode)?

I have tested this under Emacs 24.5 (Ubuntu 16.04) with a minimal `.emacs.d/init.el` file below (as suggested by the nodejs-repl.el homepage):

```
$ cat .emacs.d/init.el
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . js2-mode))

(require 'comint)
(add-to-list 'comint-preoutput-filter-functions
         (lambda (output)
           (let ((case-fold-search nil))
         (replace-regexp-in-string "\033\\[[0-9]+[A-Z]" "" output))))

(setq babel-repl-cli-arguments '("--presets"  "es2015" ))

;; Interactive commands
(eval-after-load 'js2-mode '(progn
  (define-key js2-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-b") 'babel-repl-send-buffer)
  (define-key js2-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-z") 'babel-repl)
  (define-key js2-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-r") 'babel-repl-send-current-region)
```

Other than the `init.el`, I have installed babel-repl using ELPA and its folder looks like:

```
elpa/babel-repl-20160504.1501/
```

-- EDIT --

@db48x Further info about my system:

`emacs -Q` works fine with a normal welcome screen. So does `emacs --debug-init` and `emacs --debug-init -Q`. `emacs --version` says `GNU Emacs 24.5.1`.

If tested with the following .js file:

```
$ cat test2.js 
var says = function ( ) {  return this.saying || ''; };
```

the outcome is:

```
$ emacs --script test2.js 
Loading 00debian-vars...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50cmake-data.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50mmm-mode.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50proofgeneral.el (source)...
Loading /usr/share/emacs24/site-lisp/proofgeneral/generic/proof-site.elc...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50psvn.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50python-docutils.el (source)...
Symbol's value as variable is void: var
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, with or without your configuration options. Does the problem still happen if you run `emacs -Q`? What about if you run `emacs -Q` but specifically run those two lines of your emacs configuration? Does the problem go away if you upgrade to Emacs 25?

Comment: run `emacs -Q`, then open up your init.el and use `C-x C-e` to execute just the lines you care about. Then you can compare the results after executing each one, and see (if) they're the cause.

Comment: @db48x Thanks. But when I use C-x C-e to evaluate init.el, the line `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . js2-mode))` does not seem to have effect on `.js` files that I am opening (C-x C-f) for test. Nor is the `babl-repl` command available via `M x`. The init.el above is complete. Am I missing some other system wide configuration files that load e.g. elpa/?

Comment: Well, before we dive into that, what was the result with just `emacs -Q`? If the bug still occurs, then the problem is not your configuration.

Comment: @db48x I've added updated info about my emacs configuration. Please see the edit.